# How to send value of drop down item to export plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, export, gsp

I am new in Grails. I have a drop down box and a button which generates PDF. I am able to generate and download PDF using following tag

```
<export:formats formats="['excel', 'pdf']" />
```

But, now I want to select item from drop down and pass that selected item to the export tag like below

```
<export:formats formats="['excel', 'pdf']" params ="Pass selected item here"/>
```

I tried a lot but no luck. Does anybody know how to pass selected item value of drop down to the export tag?

Comment: you can use ` params = [key: val, key1: val1]` .

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question

Answer (score 0):

In your controller use `flash.value = params?.value` inside the appropriate method. This will allow you to store the key:value pair for one transaction only.

In the GSP page define the select box value `value="${flash?.value}"` and give the select box an ID.

Assuming you want to pass the variable into the business logic, in your controller use an if statement to check for the select box value and follow the appropriate logic based on each value.

Flash is a temporary key:value storage mechanism for one request only. For more information on `flash` check out the [documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Controllers/flash.html).